# Unit test: how to test redux "Provider"?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux

I have a function like following, this is a rudux to provide EstateList.

```
import {render} from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "./Store";
import EstateList from "../estates/estateList/estateList";

function estateList() {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <EstateList />
        </Provider>,
        window.document.getElementById('estateList')

    );
}
```

And EstateList is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class EstateList extends Component {
    constructor(){
      ...
      console.log('this can not be seen');
    }
    render() {...}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        title: state.subNavReducer.title
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setSubNav: (title) => {            
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_TITLE",
                payload: title
            });
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EstateList);
```

I tried to test EstateList, like following:

```
import {shallow, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "../../../components/store/Store";
import EstateList from "../../../components/estates/estateList/estateList";
//import {EstateList} from "../../../components/estates/estateList/estateList";

describe('estate', function () {
    it('getArticlesFromDatabase ', function () {
        let app = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <EstateList />
            </Provider>
        );
    });
});
```

But it shows this warning message:

> console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
>       Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in.

How to fix it?

---

I had changed

import **{EstateList}** from "../../../components/estates/estateList/estateList";

to

import **EstateList** from "../../../components/estates/estateList/estateList";

**Then the warning message gone.**

But seems like class **estateList** still not be runed.
Cause when I run the test, I haven't seen the **console.log** which I add inside estateList's constructor.

By the way, If I changed

```
it('getArticlesFromDatabase ', function () {
    let app = shallow(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <EstateList />
        </Provider>
    );
});
```

to

```
it('getArticlesFromDatabase ', function () {
    let app = shallow(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <EstateList />
        </Provider>
    ).dive();
});
```

then I will get following error message:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(EstateList)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(EstateList)".

Comment: Does the application run correctly?

Comment: yes, it run success.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have to write a test for provider, the libary authors have already done that for you.

You are importing your EstateList component wrong, you export default'd it, and then are doing a object destructure import for named imports.

just `import EstateList from 'path'`

Comment: Okay, I modify the import. But if I simply run let app = shallow( <EstateList />); It will show following error message:

Comment: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(EstateList)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(EstateList)".

Comment: @jimmy Unlike your original code, now the store is not present. To test connected components, you either wrap them in a `Provider` (like you did) or pass the `store` prop directly.

Comment: @OrB  If I wrap EstateList in a Provider like I used to do,  the test will run success, but class EstateList still seems not be runed.

Comment: @OrB  I add "console.log('this can not be seen');" inside EstateList's constructor, but it doesent show on while test runing.

Comment: @jimmy Does it work if you use `shallow(...).dive()`?

Comment: @OrB  Do you mean let app = shallow( <Provider store={store}><EstateList /></Provider>).dive(); ?  I run it then I get the error message:

Comment: @OrB  Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(EstateList)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(EstateList)".

Comment: @jimmy You don't have to test the connected component. The container is just a thin wrapper where you pass mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. More important are tests for actions, reducers, and the shallow components, if they do something specific with their props.

Comment: @timotgl Infact, I just want to test estateList, but I don't know how to mock the redux in this case.

Comment: @jimmy In this case, you need to export the **un**connected component, so it can be imported and tested with `shallow()`. Then it's really easy to just mock the props. A good common practice is to keep the container and the component in separate files even.

Comment: @timotgl  export the unconnected component seems like a great way. It's much easier than mock provider thanks!